# Keyboard is not visible when typing a string in a text field

Tags: ios, xcode, selenium, sendkeys, appium-ios

Im trying to automate a scenario on iOS 10.3 via appium(XCUI Test) where I have to type a phone number. But there's no keyboard is visible. All I have is a numberPad type keyboard.

I use selenium `sendkeys` function and it works perfectly with other textfields which I get the keyboard visible.

I get the error as follows.

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "Keyboard is not present" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Keyboard is not present} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 11.00 seconds .
```

Comment: r u working on device or simulator? I think must be on device

Comment: I'm using a simulator ... xCode simulator

Comment: you should use Real device , or in the Simulator 
goto:  top menu of Simulator
`Hardware-> Keyboard- > ToggleSoftwareKeyBoard`
@IshiSilva

Comment: In simulator press: cmd + shift + k

Comment: I don't see that option.. I only see 'Use same layout as macOS' and 'Use hardware keyboard' :(

Comment: Please look at my answer

Answer (score 6):

Just add below steps

1. Open your Simulator
2. Select Hardware
3. Select 'Toggle Software Keyboard'

   as shown in Image[image]

Comment: You saved days of search!